# (ODI - Groovy) ODI 16171 error while setIKM() to Incremental update

Tags: groovy, oracle-data-integrator

Updated groovy script to requirement and got stuck changing default Km "Oracle  Insert/control Append" to "Oracle Incremental Update".

Tried all possibilities, changing Integration Type and setXKM() method but throws same error.

Code:

```
deploymentspec = map.getDeploymentSpec(0) 
//assign IKM
tgts = deploymentspec.getTargetNodes() 
tgts_it = tgts.iterator()
while (tgts_it.hasNext() ){
tgt_node = tgts_it.next() 
tgt_node.setIKMByName("IKM Oracle Incremental Update")
tgt_node.getOptionValue(ProcessingType.TARGET,"SYNC_JRN_DELETE").setValue("false")
tgt_node.getOptionValue(ProcessingType.TARGET,"TRUNCATE").setValue("true")
tgt_node.getOptionValue(ProcessingType.TARGET,"FLOW_CONTROL").setValue("false")
```

Can some help me to throw this.  Thanks in Advance.